# How To Get All Current User Details in a Blazor component

Tags: .net, blazor

I have a custom user table as follows :

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Username] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[UserFirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[UserLastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DateOfBirth] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[UserRole] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[IsConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
[IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
[DateCreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
```

Please tell me how to store all the user fields into a global variable on successful login. I want to be able to access all the user data every time I want into my pages ! This user table is for general purpose only. The user fields may be different in a real situation. What I need is : I want to be able to access and store as global variable all needed logged user details so I can access it when and if I need that data ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score -1):

You will need to learn about Services.  If you want access to just the user's account, used a Scoped service.  If you want to store user information accessible for all users (like for a messaging service), use Singleton.

https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/dependency-lifetimes-and-scopes/scoped-dependencies/